# Read delta table between two dates with year, month, day partition folders

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm working with Databricks. I read delta tables like this:

```
path = "/root/data/foo/year=yyyy/month=mm/day=dd"
df = spark.read.table(path).filter("year = '2021' and month = '01' and day ='04')
```

I can't use any date filter as partition is build on different folders. I'm not sure how the `.filter()` behave exactly in this context.

I've attached a job to my notebook with a daily refresh. I'm reading tables to get data from the 30 days. I don't know how to handle this when I will have overlap between two different years. So let's say I need to get data from the 15th of December 2022 to the 15th of January. How can I do this without a proper date partition column?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you use `year`, `month` and `day` as your partition columns, your path will look like `"/root/data/foo/year=yyyy/month=mm/day=dd"`.

Second, if you want to read your partition column, you should either `df = spark.read.table("/root/data/foo")` then do your filtering or you should use `df = spark.read.option("basePath", "/root/data/foo/").table(...)`.